# Help with understanding Argument Principle proof

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading complex analysis by Matthias Beck et al: https://matthbeck.github.io/papers/complex.pdf

I am trying to understand the proof of argument principle on page 137 (theorem 9.17). I understood logarithmic derivative and know we end up with 9.1 and 9.2 but what I don't understand is how did we combine 9.1 and 9.2 to get $$ \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{n_1}{z-z_1}+...+\frac{n_j}{z-z_j} - \frac{m_1}{z-p_1}+...-\frac{m_k}{z-p_k}-\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$

Can anyone please let me get started?

Comment: it comes from applying what is shown at the end of page 136, as $f$ can be written as a product of functions

Comment: so, is 9.1 considered f and 9.2 as g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is meromorphic and have a zero of order $j$ at $z_0$ then $f$ can be written as $f(z)=(z-z_0)^j g(z)$ for some meromorphic function $g$. If $f$ have a pole of order $k$ at $z_1$ then $f$ can be written as $f(z)=(z-z_1)^{-k}g(z)$ again for some meromorphic function $g$.

Thus, if $f$ have a finite number of zeros and poles then it can be written as
$$
f(z)=\overbrace{\prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k)^{o_k}}^{\text{ the zeros of }f}\cdot \overbrace{\prod_{j=1}^m (z-z_j)^{-o_j}}^{\text{ the poles of }f}\cdot g(z)
$$

for some holomorphic function $g$ and where $n,m,o_k$ and all the $o_j$ are natural numbers. Now apply what is shown at the end of the page 136 to get

$$
\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{o_k}{z-z_k}-\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{o_j}{z-z_j}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
$$

Comment: great, this makes sense. so, when i apply what is shown at the end of page 136, we will somehow end up with 9.1 and 9.2 in the process? i am only confused why the author used 9.1 and 9.2 to somehow get to the eventual equation.

Comment: the author seems to show separately the case for zeros and poles, and after it put all together